# Article after 'and' and 'or'

Tags: articles, conjunctions

When talking about two objects using *and* and *or*, when should I use *a* and *an*? Take the following sentences as an example. When is the article appropriate?

> 1. I have an orange **and** apple in my hand.
>      I have an orange **and an** apple in my hand.
> 2. I have a television **and** radio at my home.
>      I have a television **and a** radio at my home.
> 3. I would love to have an orange **or an** apple in breakfast.
>      I would love to have an orange **or** apple in breakfast.
> 4. I had some money three months ago, I could buy a television **or a** radio.
>      I had some money three months ago, I could buy a television **or** radio.
> 5. I have a mango **and an** apple in my hand.
>      I have an apple **and** mango in my hand.

Comment: Do **NOT** ask the same question more than once. That's not the way the Stack Exchange works.

Comment: @J.R. - I don't see another similar question from this user. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Martha - The duplicate question was deleted. Here is the [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17116), if you can see it.

Answer (score 13):

In general, you need to repeat the article. The conjunction *and* or *or* joins two noun groups, each of which need to include an article (which can be the null article sometimes, of course).

> I have an orange and an apple in my hand.
>   I had some money three months ago, I could buy a television or a radio.

There is an exception for *and*, when you are not saying that there are two objects, but that there is a single object which can be designated by two nouns. For example:

> I have a washing machine and a dryer. [I have two appliances.]
>   I have a washing machine and dryer. [I have a single appliance which has both functions.]

This is rare, however. In this example, the standard term would be “washer-dryer”. Without using that term, other possibilities include “washing machine and dryer combination” or “washing machine cum dryer” or “washing machine with dryer”.

It is possible to have a pattern like “a NOUN1 and NOUN2 NOUN3”, where “NOUN1 and NOUN2” is a complement of NOUN3. Here NOUN1 and NOUN2 take the null article; the article *a* is attached to NOUN3. So the article is repeated.

> I have a steak and kidney pie in the oven.
>   I have a steak and kidney pie and an apple strudel in the oven.

With *or*, you can sometimes leave out the second article. There isn't a clear difference in meaning, but leaving out the article tends to indicate that there is a given object whose nature is in doubt, whereas including the article tends to indicate that there are two objects and there is a choice between these two. It is not common to leave out the second article.

Comment: I have a steak and kidney pie in the oven.

Comment: @oerkelens Heh. You have a pie, with the null article before *steak* and the null article before *kidney*.

Comment: I know, and it's a lovely pie :) To the casual observer though, there is an indefinite article before _steak_. Maybe an extra exception to add to the one you gave? :)

Comment: @oerkelens Not an exception, a case where applying the rule is a bit difficult. But I agree, I should have mentioned it. Done.

Comment: Then there's "We're having steak and kidney pie and apple strudel for dinner."  Just to further complicate the issue.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not providing an alternative answer, but adding, for future reference (and when this answer is linked to as a previous answer to duplicate questions) that this answer applies to both definite and indefinite articles.

In other words, you can replace 'a/an' with 'the' and Gilles's answer still applies.