# "the apple and orange" vs "the apple and the orange"

Tags: articles

When some nouns are definitive, can you say for example "the apple and orange" instead of the "the apple and the orange"?  Which one is preferred?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Article after 'and' and 'or'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/article-after-and-and-or)

Comment: @ParibusCeteris it does not. it's about "the" and not "a/an". I think you cannot omit the second "a/an". Interestingly, the other question also uses orange and apple example

Comment: I think the point that needs to be clarified in the other post is that the same rule applies to both definite and indefinite articles. Apart from that, it does in fact answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, but usually you would omit an article and let it govern both nouns.

`The apple and [the] orange are on the table.`